# Getting TD cell width to wrap around div with specified width %

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, word-wrap

Here's my current HTML / CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/

And here's a screenshot that annotates what I'd like to try to do:

[image]

Basically, I'd like the width of the parent TD to dynamically wrap based on the width of the nested div.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Only texts wrap, a "width" can't wrap.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not phrasing it properly. You'll see the effect which I am referring to by just typing "la" into the cell. The cell width will collapse. From this: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/35/ to this: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/39/. I would think you would be able to accomplish the same effect by wrapping "la la la la la la la la la" in a div with a width of 25%, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand. Table text will wrap if it doesn#'t fit (unless you specifically disabled it).

Comment: Are you wanting the `<td>` to "inherit" the width of its child element (

Comment: why don't you set the td width: td {width:15%}

Comment: Are you wanting the `<td>` to "inherit" the width of its child element (`<div>`)?

Comment: You need to rethink what you want to do.  If the content div's size is 50% of the cell's width, and then you set the cell's width to div size, now the div would need to reduce to half the width to keep itself at 50% and once that happens the cell would need to reduce in size to match the div and so on. So it never ends. Either the div width or the td width needs to be based on something else instead of each other.

Comment: all, appreciate your input on this. you all give some valid points to consider. it sounds like there's a consensus around the fact that I need to think through the design approach a little more. given my original question, mr. william niu did solve it with the jquery approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...as Sheepy pointed out, what you are asking does not seem to make sense, initially. But if you really want to make the TD adjust with the inner DIV, you will need to do some JavaScript...

Say, you have the following table cell:

```
<td rowspan="4" id="tdwrap"> <div id="divwrap">...</div></td>
```

You could have the following javascript calls:

```
// set cell width to its inner div width (in pixel)
$('#tdwrap').width($('#divwrap').width());

// set the div width back to its parent cell width (in pixel)
$('#divwrap').width($('#tdwrap').width());
```

And then, you can set the width of the div:

```
#divwrap {
    width: 30%;
}
```

This way, you can let the cell width to adjust to its inner div's width, which is based on its parent cell's width! :p

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/S8Bne/89/

Note that I have used the jQuery library in the code snippet.

Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

This is just some advice but from my experience it's hard to get Tables and Div's to play well together especially if you have a cross browser testing environment.

Obviously try and use only Div's wherever possible unless its a situation with a large about of tabular data then it may be appropriate to use tables. The example you have seems to warrant the use of tables. I would personally try and scrap the in table div's and just apply CSS to the table cells.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `style="width: -moz-fit-content;"` for the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

click on fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/93/

`<table style="table-layout: fixed;">`
`<tr>`
`<td style="word-wrap:break-word">la la la la la la la la la la</td>`
`</tr>`
`</table>`

Notice **style** attributes of table and td

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-complicating your presentation.

You can target the `td` just like a `div` via JS, JQuery (if that's your end goal).

Since it looks like you need a table layout here: could you just assign a padding to the `td` and allow the content to flow in naturally?

Even if you keep the `div` wrapper: by NOT assigning a width, the `div` will be bound to the padding of the cell (it's parent).